# Having trouble writing custom query to update mySql database

Tags: reactjs, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, axios

Ok, trying to update mySql database using Java Spring Hibernate backend and a JPA repository, with react front end with axios calls. Not sure exactly where I am going wrong as this is my first time working with this.

This is my custom query...

```
@Modifying
    @Query("UPDATE Item i SET i.title=?1  WHERE i.id=?2")
    void editItem(@Param("title") String title, @Param("id") long id);
```

and this is my call from React using axios

```
    Axios.put(`http://localhost:8080/editItem?title=${title}&id=${id}`)
```

This causes an error in my back-end

Resolved [org.springframework.web.bind.MissingPathVariableException: Missing URI template variable 'id' for method parameter of type Long]

Obviously, I am doing something wrong passing the ID, but for the life of me I can't figure it out

Answer (score 1):

```
@Modifying
@Query("UPDATE Item i SET i.title=?1  WHERE i.id=?2")
void editItem(String title, long id);
```

Try just delete the @Param annotation

Param is using when query is looks like WHERE i.id=:id